# Rails: Is JSON still REST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm still very new to web development, so please bear with me if this question is really stupid.

I'm trying to follow a REST principles, however, I really appreciate how JSON flows with Ruby and anything that is connecting externally through an API. I know that its pretty standard in REST to input parameters directly into the URL like so: myurl.com/ExampleModel/MyIDParameter and send the JSON (if there is any) to that URI, right?

What I would like to know is: Is it against REST principles to remove the parameter from the URI (and the routing if I will never use it) and include the parameter in the JSON?

For example, instead of calling this:

```
myurl.com/ExampleModel/id
{
    "name" : "My Name",
    "anotherParameter" : "A random string"
}
```

You would call this:

```
myurl.com/ExampleModel
{
    "id" : 512,
    "name" : "My Name",
    "anotherParameter" : "A random string"
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for a guy named [Steve Klabnik](http://www.steveklabnik.com) or @SteveKlabnik, but don't let me get in the middle of the flame-war that's about to start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Disclaimer: I don't program in Ruby, so I cant answer specific questions on Ruby. But my answer is directed to your question of REST principles.

Finally, the answer:
This is a matter of how your application plays out. I will first explain a common approach used by developers. I mentioned ***common*** and is not the golden rule.

When you specify `myurl.com/ExampleModel/id`. A common meaning of such a pattern is used in with GET or PUT operation. GET in the sense that I want information on some object of ID value `id`. PUT in the sense that I have some request body attached with the request to be Updated to the Data Store whose Object have a ID of `id`.

Your second URL when you mentioned just `myurl.com/ExampleModel`, A common interpretation is to show me all the records from the `ExampleModel` collection. This is pretty much the default behaviour used by developers who write APIs.

So, does it break REST principles when you want to do things, the answer is NO. But if you hand your API to other people, the might get a bit confused over it.

So there you have it. Now it's upto you to decide what is best suited for your application.

Comment: Thats awesome. Thank you for that explanation. I've been used to a single URI (for a specific model) with different HTTP Methods and variable request bodies for the different types. I should probably follow the common approach, just so that I can seamlessly work with other developers, but its good to know that the way that I thought up doesn't go against REST, at least.

Comment: You see, the reason for taking the approach I mentioned is when you are doing a GET or PUT, you don't want a heavy payload going up. You don't really need a Request Body just to attach a ID to it. That can be done on the URI (one single request, short and light-weight). I forgot to mention that the one without the ID in the URI can also be used to do POST operation as you don't have a ID when inserting a new value. In short, to get one object or update one object, typically used with id in the URI. To get collection of object or insert new object, typically no ID is mentioned in the URI.

Comment: Oh. I didn't even think about the weight of the request (not something I normally ignore). It makes sense that you want to keep the requests and decisions as light as possible as well as giving more flexibility to the base routing actions (If it has an ID, do this, if it does not, do this, etc). It really is starting to make more sense why they do it the way that it is structured in my reading material. Why process more than you have to when routing is done so optimally already.

Comment: Exactly. You'll start getting more feel of this design flow and REST as you go along. It does not work like functions and methods. But here, I explained what is a common and well thought-out approach. From here, you play with the URI designs that best suit your application. But base fundamentals used by developers all relate down to this.

Comment: Okay. Thats perfect. I think this best answers the question I asked for anyone that comes across the question. Is what I did okay? Yes. Is it optimal? No. Is it the standard? No. Should I use it? Its personal preference, but if you are still at the beginning and flexible enough, it would be a good idea to follow the other resource/URI model. Thank you for the help on this. I'm sorry for the stupid comments and questions I've made, but I want to setup good habits from the start and build on a strong foundation.

Answer (score 4):

If `myurl.com/ExampleModel` identifies a *unique* Resource, you can use this as an URI. But I doubt it.

Can your application also have a *different* Resource Representation like this?

```
{
    "id" : 513,
    "name" : "Some Other Name",
    "anotherParameter" : "A differnet random string"
}
```

If yes, what is the URI for it?

I recommend to use the first form to address such a Resource Representations:

```
GET http://myurl.com/ExampleModel/513
```

**Note:** Your JSON is not valid since it is missing double quotes and commas.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I will fix the JSON. I haven't actually written JSON in a while, but rather relied on conversions. I just lost the habit, I guess. However, yes, I was expecting to have resource representations just like that. The URI would be the exact same, however I would keep the id parameter out of the URI (and routing) and move it to the JSON.

Comment: You can't do that. If you want to identify *different* Resources you have to use *different* URIs. URI stands for 'Uniform resource identifier' which means that it (uniquely) identifies a Resource.

Comment: Oh. You meant on the same URI. I mean that I would have all calls for a certain resource made on one URI, but all of the parameters would and actions would be decided by either the JSON or the HTTP Method. However, there will obviously be certain occasions when those two won't be optimal and I will have URI extentions ('/ExampleModel/differentFunction'), but that would be strictly for actions and wouldn't contain any parameters in the URI.

Comment: I recommend to first read some good tutorial on what REST is all about. And please don't thing about 'functions' and 'methods' when you think abour REST. Think about Resources and Representations. See http://www.infoq.com/articles/webber-rest-workflow

Comment: Sorry. I'm just so used to including the whole picture in a problem, rather than isolating it. I know that its not good practice when asking questions, so I will work on that in the future. Thank you for the resource, though! The REST architecture does directly affect how everything behaves from request to action, though. Thats where I got to in my thought process.

Comment: I'm sorry for any comments that are just plain wrong. I am still very new and I'm going to still come across so many "Ooohhh! Thats how it is!" moments. I really appreciate the feedback on this. I just want to make sure I develop good habits at the beginning of my learning/journey. Thank you so much for your help on this!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the format of the data exchange has anything to do with what REST is or isn't.

Go for it.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. It really helps to get others' feedback on this as I'm still just learning and I don't want to start off on the wrong foot.

Answer (score 1):

REST is really more of a concept than a strictly designed protocol. Most people equate REST to simply using all of the HTTP verbs to do different things on the same URL, and there's some validity to that way of thinking.

But, if you want some information about how to use the original intent behind REST to actually make a good API:

http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-07-03-nobody-understands-rest-or-http

http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-08-07-some-people-understand-rest-and-http

So if you follow the principles from the blog, it's pretty important to refer to resources by their ID, in the URL. But it's your API and there's no strict rules on how things must be done, just recommendations on how to make your API more discoverable.

Comment: Thats what I thought, however, I didn't want to assume and go down the wrong path. I guess, with this, its a mix of comfort and compatibility. How do both design types work with the way that I think and how easily will other developers be able to adjust to my code/APIs. I do love using the REST protocol. Its very object-y.